# OnClick event not working properly in Powershell

Tags: powershell, onclick

I created the script below.
This issue is that when I run the script via the command line (powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted  -file "C:\Sander\5.ps1) the clickevent, $OwnButton_Click, is not working, the write-host line is not displayed.

When I run the script via Powershell ISE, the first time the clickevent, $OwnButton_Click, is not working, the write-host line is not displayed, but when I run it the second time in ISE the clickevent, $OwnButton_Click, is working, the write-host line is displayed.

What am I missing here?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Data Entry Form'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$OwnButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OwnButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,120)
$OwnButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OwnButton.Name = 'OwnButton'
$OwnButton.Text = 'OwnButton'
$OwnButton.Add_Click($SanderButton_Click)
$OwnButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::None
$form.AcceptButton = $OwnButton
$form.Controls.Add($OwnButton)

$OwnButton_Click = {
Write-Host Just some crap -ForegroundColor Cyan
}

$form.Topmost = $true

$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: In the `Add_Click` you use the variable `$SanderButton_Click`. Later you define the scriptblock `OwnButton_Click`. The scriptblock needs to be defined before you use it and of course the name of the variables have to match...

Comment: $SanderButton_Click is corrected.

What do you mean with 'The scriptblock needs to be defined before you use it' ?
Do I have to change the postion of the code?

Comment: Yes the position is the problem. A ScriptBlock is a little script in `{ }`, mostly stored in a variable to use it later, like you did with `$OwnButton_Click`. But at the `Add_Click` the ScriptBlock doesn't exist, because it is defined later in the script. That's the reason why it will work the second time you execute the script in ISE. The variable is still present from the first execution.